# Table row indented

Tags: android, scrollview, android-tablelayout

I have a `TableLayout` which I populate with a bunch of `ImageView`s so that the user can draw a diagram with icons on the side. But for some reason the `TableRow`s aren't starting from the edge of the table, but rather a few pixels in, this gives the layout an ugly look which I want to get rid of. I don't have any margin/padding assigned so I have no idea why this is happening. My `TableLayout` is inside a `HorizontalScrollView` and `VerticalScrollView` so that I can scroll across the table.
[image]

Here is the xml(the `ImageViews`s are being dynamically added)

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="left">


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lvTools"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editScrollView">

    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/drawTable"
            android:visibility="visible"></TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvTools"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />

<Button
    android:background="@drawable/custom_buttons"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Drawing"
    android:id="@+id/btnNew"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<Button
    android:background="@drawable/custom_buttons"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Load Drawing"
    android:id="@+id/btnLoad"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editScrollView"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mainScrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editLayout">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this attribute from your `TableLayout`.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
```

Comment: wow.......can't believe I did not see that. I'll accept it in 8 minutes when it will allows me